# Only size 1 arrays can be converted to python scalars

Tags: numpy-random

I created a 3 dimensional object using `numpy.random` module such as

```
import numpy as np
b = np.random.randn(4,4,3)
```

Why can't we cast type float to `b`?

[TypeError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlwLD.png)

[actual code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ssnc.jpg)

Comment: What do you mean by cast type float to `b`? Please provide the code that breaks and the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't `float(b)` because `b` isn't a number, it's a multidimensional array/matrix. If you're trying to convert every element to a Python float, that's a bad idea because numpy numbers are more precise, but if you *really* want to do that for whatever reason, you can do `b.tolist()`, which returns a Python `list` of `float`s. However, I don't believe you can have a numpy matrix of native Python types because that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Thanks for your time and answer. I've included two images named TypeError and actual code. I'm requesting you to take a look and help me to understand the essence of casting the bias.

Comment: @StarkWayne Alright, I'll take a look at those once I get home because my school internet blocks imgur.

Comment: @StarkWayne For future reference, all text-based information pertinent to the problem (code, errors, etc) should be included in the post as text. Also, your error is that a list of multiple decimal values can't be converted to a single floating-point number. Your actual code should theoretically work because the data type has size 1, but your test in the console doesn't work because there are multiple numbers in `b`.